# FindAll inside model hooks 'afterFind' not working using sequilize in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a project in nodejs using sequelize.
I am tring to do a FindAll inside a model but I am getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
```

I import the models like this:

```
const db = require('./index');
```

And in the model hooks I am trying to do this:

```
hooks: {
  afterFind: async function(User){

    let ranks_db = await db.rank.findAll({ });
    // let rank = await checkRank(User.exp);

    User['exp'] = {
      value: User.exp,
      rank
    };

    return User;

  }
}
```

The findAll it is working in the controller but not in the model
. I want to know if it is posible to do a FindAll inside a model

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have a circular dependency between your models and that `db.rank` has not been populated yet when the Model you are showing here is constructed. Instead of importing the models via `require` you can reference them from the `sequelize` variable that is passed into the Model.

```js
module.exports = function Model(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('user', { /* columns */ }, {
    hooks: {
      afterFind: async function(user) {
        const ranks = await sequelize.models.rank.findAll();
        // user.ranks = ranks;
      },
    }
  });
}
```